# How to get slice of an array where date is the key of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has date (e.g "2011-10-31") as key and some value associated with it. The array is sorted. Now, I want to slice the array by giving starting date and ending date? How can I do it in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple loop over it:

```
function getRange($array, $start, $end) {
    $inRange = false;
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $date => $value) {
        if($date >= $start && !$inRange) {
            $inRange = true;
        }
        if($date > $end) {
            break;
        }
        if($inRange) {
            $result[$date] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

If start and end date match the keys in the array exactly, you could also use a combination of [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) (but might not be faster):

```
function getRange($array, $start, $end) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $starti = array_search($start, $keys);
    $endi = array_search($end, $keys);
    return array_slice($array, $starti, $endi-$starti+1);
}
```

I assumed you want to have the start and end date in the result array.

Of course you have to think about what you should happen if the start and/or end date are not in the array.